# Adding a self-signed certificate to the "trusted list"

Tags: curl, wget, ssl, certificates, browser

I've generated a self-signed certificate for my build server and I'd like to globally trust the certificate on my machine, as I created the key myself and I'm sick of seeing warnings.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. How can I take the certificate and globally trust it so that browsers (Google Chrome), CLI utilities (wget, curl), and programming languages (Python, Java, etc.) trust the connection to `https://example.com` without asking questions?

Comment: All the TLS should be vectored through OpenSSL, so that's the place to look for documentation. In this case: http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#selfsigned-openssl looks useful.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The simple answer to this is that pretty much each application will handle it differently.

Also OpenSSL and GNUTLS (the most widely used certificate processing libraries used to handle signed certificates) behave differently in their treatment of certs which also complicates the issue. Also operating systems utilize different mechanisms to utilize "root CA" used by most websites.

That aside, giving Debian as an example. Install the `ca-certificates` package:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

You then copy the public half of your untrusted CA certificate (the one you use to sign your CSR) into the CA certificate directory (as root):

```
cp cacert.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates
```

*NOTE:* Certificate needs to have `.crt` extension for it to be picked up.

And get it to rebuild the directory with your certificate included, run as root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

and select the `ask` option, scroll to your certificate, mark it for inclusion and select ok.

Most browsers use their own CA database, and so tools like `certutil` have to be used to modify their contents (on Debian that is provided by the `libnss3-tools` package). For example, with Chrome you run something along the lines of:

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n "My Homemade CA" -i /path/to/CA/cert.file
```

Firefox will allow you to browse to the certificate on disk, recognize it a certificate file and then allow you to import it to Root CA list.

Most other commands such as `curl` take command line switches you can use to point at your CA,

```
 curl --cacert  /path/to/CA/cert.file https://...
```

or drop the SSL validation altogether

```
 curl --insecure https://...
```

The rest will need individual investigation if the `ca-certificates` like trick does not sort it for that particular application.

Comment: Also, as noted [here](http://www.mikepilat.com/blog/2011/05/adding-a-certificate-authority-to-the-java-runtime/), adding CA certificates for Java is likewise a separate matter.

Comment: After copying the certificate to /usr/share/ca-certificates, I can't see it in the `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron That happened to me to. I resolved it by renaming the cert from `whatever.pem` to `whatever.crt`.

Comment: ref https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html

Comment: FYI, I had a cert file named `.cer`, and that didn't work. I had to rename it to `.crt` for it to be recognized.

Comment: I didn't need to install `ca-certificates` on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: The file name has to match `/usr/share/ca-certificates/*.crt` in order to be picked by the utility.

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure only lists the existing certs under the mozilla subdirectory, not the one I added.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can now add certs to Chrome via the Settings page, without the need for the certutil tool.

Answer (score 99):

### Non Interactive Approach

For use in a non-interactive context (e.g. a chef recipe) you can use the following sequence.

```
sudo cp my.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

- Tested and works on debian 5/6 & Ubuntu 14.04.
- For more information, see `man update-ca-certificates`

This method is preferred over @Drav's method, since `/usr/share/` is typically reserved for files added by the OS / `apt-get`.

Comment: It is better to copy the files to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` as mentioned in the man pages

Comment: FYI the A must be a `.crt`, I found `.cert` claimed it was added but did not help

Comment: will this work with Chrome?

Answer (score 14):

### Fedora

On Fedora 23, add the .pem or .der file to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and run `sudo update-ca-trust extract`.

See `man update-ca-trust` for details, e.g. whether to use /etc or /usr.

### Alpine

Add the .pem to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and run `update-ca-certificates`.

The sources for this Alpine tooling live at https://github.com/alpinelinux/ca-certificates/blob/898ab81b51730dcd175069956d6e792385c9f457/update-ca.c#L18

Answer (score 10):

In centos:

```
cp *.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
update-ca-trust extract
```

Comment: When I do `openssl connect` should I be specifying this /anchors folder? I'm still getting an error "`self signed certs`

Answer (score 9):

**Non Interactive Approach (Oct'18)**
for recent debian based systems

There's a distinction between adding a cert to the host's store and activating it so that applications really utilize those. An existing cert in the store isn't necessarily used (although i have to admit that still a lot of packages are getting it wrong anyway)
This can get confusing when you setup a package which considers `/etc/ca-certificate.conf` and simply refuses to use your cert although it has been added without error.
You need to tell `update-ca-certificates` explicitly to (not just copy but) activate the cert by adding it to `/etc/ca-certificate.conf` or `/etc/ca-certificate/update.d`.

```
CERT=mycert.crt
cp /mypath/to/$CERT /usr/share/ca-certificates/$CERT
    # notice the + sign which tells to activate the cert!!!
echo "+$CERT" >/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/activate_my_cert
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates;
```

Now here it gets confusing as there's a way to implicitly trust a certificate by using a different path:

```
CERT=mycert.crt
cp /mypath/to/$CERT /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$CERT
update-ca-certificates;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp my.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

These 2 lines above does not work with me at the first time.

After investigation, it turned out that many certificates are excludes in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` because the line starts by `!`

So i have to remove the 1st character in all lines which starts by `!`

```
sudo sed -i '/^!/s/^.//g' /etc/ca-certificates.conf
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Now curl works without the need of `--cacert` option !!

Comment: You've just re-enabled all of the certs that were disabled, e.g., ones from bad actors or expired.  That was not clever