# Adding a self-signed cert in Linux Mint 20.1?

Tags: linux-mint, ssl, certificates

I'm playing around with aspnetcore in Linux Mint (an Ubuntu derivative), and I've run into issues with the dotnet dev-cert. The dotnet cli's "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" command doesn't work on Linux.

So I'm trying to figure out how to install and trust a self-signed cert.

Browsing around, I found this:

[Adding a self-signed certificate to the "trusted list"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list)

But that's eight years old.

Is it still current?

Comment: Give it a try, the accepted answer is nine hours old right now. If something does not work you can then ask about that part.

Comment: These instructions should still be correct.