# Security certificate is issued to another domain after adding my self signed certificate to ca-certificates

Tags: certificates, pop-os

following [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90607), I imported my self signed certificate into ca-certificates. But when I try to connect to the server using [Dino](https://dino.im/), I get an error telling me that the security certificate is issued to another domain, which I don't understand.

The certificate uses the public IP as identity and it's verified by the public IP too, it's a self signed certificate. Can someone please explain to me what's the meaning of the error?

[image]

I generated the certificate using `prosodyctl cert generate public_ip`. The certificate seems valid since from other apps like Monocles chat, after telling it it's okay that is self signed it worked. So maybe the problem is the way I imported it to ca-certificates? What I did is: I copied the certificate from the server to the client and put it in the ca-certificates folder. Then, I executed `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` to import it.

Comment: Does the certificate have a "Subject Alternative Name" under Details?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Does your JID (XMPP account ID) also use the IP address as its "@domain" or does it use a domain name?

Comment: It uses the IP address. Like this user@public_ip. Could it be it's a bug of Dino? Do you know any other way of checking if a certificate is valid? I found `openssl verify cert_file`, but the verification fails because it's self signed.